# Debian amd64 mirror size too large

Tags: debian, mirror

I have rsync'ed debian amd64 to my local (Omnios) box using the recommended ftpsync too.

The size of my mirror is 143 GB. I was led to believe from debian and other sources it should be around 80 GB.

here my ftpsync.conf:

```
MIRRORNAME=`hostname`
TO="/opt/local/share/httpd/htdocs/debian"
RSYNC_PATH="debian/"
RSYNC_HOST=mirrors.dotsrc.org
LOGDIR="${BASEDIR}/log"
LOG="${LOGDIR}/${NAME}.log"
ARCH_EXCLUDE="alpha arm armel armhf hppa hurd-i386 i386 ia64 kfreebsd-amd64 kfreebsd-i386 m68k mipsel mips powerpc s390 s390x sh sparc source"
LOGROTATE=14
LOCK="${TO}/Archive-Update-in-Progress-${MIRRORNAME}"
```

rsync-ftpsync.error.0 has no errors.

Why is my mirror so large?

Answer (score 2):

My assumption would be because it mirrors both 'amd64' and 'all', both of which are >90GB ( https://www.debian.org/mirror/size ). My ARCH_EXCLUDE is the same as what you've posted, and my mirror is ~162GB currently.

If you don't need a full mirror you'll probably save a LOT of space if you use a proxy server - https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/apt-cacher-ng

If you're just spinning up a lot of similar virtual machines or something, your proxy cache may be less than 10GB (just guessing).